# Java Enum.valueOf - How to handle Class<E> type parameter as an enum if it can also be Integer or boolean?

Tags: java, class, generics, enums

I have a method that parses excel cell (those cells have always an excel type of String). Sometimes those cells contains regular types like int or boolean and sometimes enum values:

```
  private static <E> Object parseCellStringValue(String value, Class<E> targetType) {
    if (value.isBlank()) {
      return null;
    } else if (targetType == String.class) {
      return value;
    } else if (targetType == Integer.class || targetType == int.class) {
      return Integer.parseInt(value);
/// ...
/// ...
/// ...
    } else if (targetType == Boolean.class || targetType == boolean.class) {
      return Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
    } else if (targetType == AttributeKind.class) {
      return AttributeKind.valueOf(value);
    } else if (targetType == ReturnType.class) {
      return ReturnType.valueOf(value);
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException(
        String.format("Unsupported target type passed: %s", targetType));
  }
```

`AttributeKind` and `AttributeType` are enums, and there will be many more enums in this method in the future so I wanted to simplify this by replacing those ifs with one if branch that would handle all enums.

I wrote something like this:

```
 else if (targetType.isEnum()) {
   return Enum.valueOf(targetType, value);
 }
```

But the IDE shows an error on `targetType` inside `valueOf` :
*Required type: Class<T>

Provided: Class<E>

reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that E conforms to Enum<T>*

As if the compiler does not know that it just checked that `targetType` is certainly an enum. I have tried casting `targetType` to an `Enum` but that does not work. I do not know how to solve my problem in Java. I suspect it may be impossible to do as the `<E>` generic type has to extend `Enum<E>` but then the Integer and Boolean cases would not work.

Is it possible to write simple and elegant solution in Java that would handle all enums?

Comment: NON-elegant solution (workaround): `return Enum.valueOf((Class) targetType, value);` -- but using Raw Type is NOT recommended ([Raw Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8))

Comment: You can use [`Class#getEnumConstants()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants()) to manually search the constants for one with the correct name. In your case, you'll have to cast each element of the returned array to `Enum<?>` to get the constant's name. If no constant with the correct name is found, throw an exception. This will avoid raw types and unchecked casts.

Comment: `return Enum.valueOf(targetType.asSubclass(Enum.class), value);` but it still produces a warning, because `Enum.class` has the type `Class<Enum>` instead of `Class<Enum<?>>`.